# (Cordova / Phonegap) Problems with WifiManager.addNetwork() method of Android

Tags: android, cordova, wifimanager

Currently I am writing an app in **Cordova 3.4.0** that should import Wifi settings from a source, like a file or database.

If I use the [WifiManager.addNetwork](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork%28android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration%29) method of **Android**, it **always returns -1** for "failed".

On the other hand: If I use the same code in the [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method of a blank [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), the settings are added and I return the ID of the new entry.

The app is developed for **API 10 to 19** and I call the Cordova code **from a plugin context**.

The android app has the following [permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

My test device: **Samsung Galaxy Y** (**GT-S5360**) with **Android 2.3.6**.

Is that a bug or a feature? There seems to be no details in the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) e.g. that tells more.

If I look at the official [Android code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e85fc6220adbb7d81457579ba0e98c2e329a39a6/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java), I only see a hint to an external *IWifiManager* service that seems to be device specific.

Here is my code:

```
private void addWifiSettings() {
    String ssid = "MY_NETWORK";
    String pwd = "my_secrect_password";

    Context ctx = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    // in blank activity project it is:
    // 
    // ctx = this.getApplicationContext();

    WifiManager man = (WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();

    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wc.priority = 1;
    wc.networkId = -1;
    wc.hiddenSSID = false;

    // SSID and password
    wc.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(pwd).concat("\"");

    wc.allowedProtocols.clear();
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

    wc.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

    String wifiAction;
    int netId;
    if (wc.networkId < 0) {
        // if network is NEW

        wifiAction = "add";
        netId = man.addNetwork(wc);
    }
    else {
        // if network EXISTS and should be UPDATED

        wifiAction = "update";
        netId = man.updateNetwork(wc);
    }

    // !!! AT THIS POINT IT ALWAYS RETURNS -1 IN CORDOVA/PHONEGAP PROJECT !!!
    if (netId < 0) {
        throw new Exception(String.format("Could not %s network: %s",
                                          wifiAction,
                                          wc.SSID));
    }

    if (man.saveConfiguration() == false) {
        throw new Exception("Could not save network configuration!");
    }

    man.enableNetwork(netId, false);
}
```

Comment: I try to do nearly the same... i wanna add a wifi network via a button in my app. Did you find a plguin or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`networkId` is [ignored](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)), so you don't need to set it.

I wrote a [working Cordova plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard) that interfaces with WifiManager. Abbreviated relevant code for WPA:

```
wifi.SSID = newSSID;
wifi.preSharedKey = newPass;
wifi.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
wifi.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wifi.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wifi.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wifi.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wifi.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wifi.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
wifiManager.addNetwork(wifi);
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

That should get you started in figuring out why your code isn't working. I'd guess that you're trying to do too much with the WifiConfiguation object and need to pare it down somewhat. It looks like you're trying to set the wc to accept a WEP or WPA network.